# Autohotkey script to map Caps lock + X to spesified characters, script almost works

Tags: vim, key, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, key-bindings

I have a norwegian keyboard. So I have to click **RCtrl + 7** to get **{** and **RCtrl + 8** to get **[** etc.

This is super annoying when I'm programming so I am trying to map the caps lock key to do the same as the RCtrl key.

So I wrote this AutoHotKey script:

```
SetCapsLockState AlwaysOff
CapsLock & 0::Send }
CapsLock & 1::Send ^1
CapsLock & 2::Send @
CapsLock & 3::Send £
CapsLock & 4::Send $
CapsLock & 5::Send €
CapsLock & 6::Send ^6
CapsLock & 7::Send {
CapsLock & 8::Send [
CapsLock & 9::Send ]
```

The weird thing is that everything works perfectly, except for:

```
"CapsLock & 7::Send {"
"CapsLock & 0::Send }"
```

I just want CapsLock + 7 to give me the character { and
CapsLock + 0 to give me the character }

For some reason that does not work??

PS. if you have a version of this for vim that would also be ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are special symbols used to send keys like `{Enter}`.

Use [`SendRaw` {](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) or `Send {raw}{`